# Running function once (In a while loop)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, animation

Trying to run my function in my while loop with an animation where I move squares and I only want it to run once. Don't get it to work. If I use setInterval it will just animate multiple times. And how I have it now doesn't animate at all. This is how it looks now. Appreciate some tips. Thanks!

EDIT - The squares are animated to different positions depending on count id.

```
<?php
...
$count = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ //many rows
$count = $count + 1
    $id= $rows['id']; //different id's for each row


?>
<script>
    var ID = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
            var count = '<?php echo $count; ?>';      
</script>

<div id="squares" style="height:50px; width:50px; position:relative; background:black;" >

<script>
    document.getElementById('squares').id = ID; //make div id "squares" to ID

//So here the it doesn't work.
function(){
    if(count == 1){
    $('#' + ID).animate({left: (700), top: (300)}, 2000);
    $('#' + ID).animate({left: (300), top: (500)}, 2000);
    }
    if(count == 2){
    $('#' + ID).animate({left: (100), top: (400)}, 2000);
    $('#' + ID).animate({left: (100), top: (800)}, 2000);
    }
}

</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: 'setInterval' => loop   vs   'setTimeout' => wait and run one time

Comment: First you should separate HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and PHP. Do not put everything into the same file as this will only get you code soup.

Comment: Why do you call a function inside a loop if you only want it to run once?

Comment: setTimeout runs it over and over again too :/ @Jahnux73 .

Comment: Well this is just a simple example, got it separated better in real code ;) @str

Comment: Well, the real code contains hundreds of rows. I dont want to put function outside becuase I have to save all variables for them self. And it is more variables than just id ;) @feeela

Comment: At which point in the loop do you need it to run? The first time? When a specific value is read from the database?

Comment: I want it to run directly, once. Yes when the while loop hands out the values of the id's it is supposed to animate the div with the specified id. @bukko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // NOTE: I suspect what you want to do is run one animation after the other,
        // you need a callback function for that.
        $('.toBeAnimated1').animate({ left: (700), top: (300) }, 2000, function() {
            $('.toBeAnimated1').animate({ left: (300), top: (500) }, 2000);
        });
        $('.toBeAnimated2').animate({ left: (100), top: (400) }, 2000, function() {
            $('.toBeAnimated2').animate({ left: (100), top: (800) }, 2000);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
...
$count = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ //many rows
$count = $count + 1
    $id= $rows['id']; //different id's for each row
    ?>
    <div id="<? echo $id; ?>" class="toBeAnimated<? echo $count; ?>" style="height:50px; width:50px; position:relative; background:black;" >
<?
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clearly there are better ways. You might want to consider saving the values for your squares (start position, end position, etc.) in the database so you can make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i can see is that in the PHP while loop you are writing a bunch of JS scripts, each dealing with the animation of a single element. You should change that to a single JS scripts that animates all your elements:

```
<?php
...    
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ //many rows
    $id= $rows['id']; //different id's for each row
    $left = $rows['left']; // <---- replace this with your logic for determining top and left
    $top = $rows['top'];
?>

<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="square" style="height:50px; width:50px; position:relative; background:black;" data-animateLeft="<?php echo $left; ?>" data-animateTop="<?php echo $top; ?>">

<?php
}
?>

<script>
$('.square').each(function(){
   $this = $(this);
   $this.animate({left: +$this.data('animateLeft'), top: +$this.data('animateTop')}, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Seeing your point. But each square are going to be animated to different locations. Will se if I can make something good out of this! :) @Tibos

Comment: @Alex Goransson Check out this edit. You can also keep a data structure in JS with the coordinates for each item that you fill from PHP, but i think it is more semantic like this.